# Purrr and mapping vector-output functions

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I'm trying to get my head around `purrr`, but I'm struggling with something that should be easy.

Say I have the following data for males and females

```
n <- 1000
toydata <- data.frame(
  sex = as.character(ifelse(rnorm(n)>0, "M", "F")),
  value = rnorm(n)
)
```

Now, I want to calculate the following five quantiles of the value column

```
p <- c(.1, .25, .5, .75, .9)
```

When I mutate + map using the quantile function, a list of vectors is returned as stored as an additional column, as expected:

```
toydata %>%
  group_by(sex) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(
    quantiles = map(data, ~quantile(.$value, p, na.rm=TRUE))
  )


# A tibble: 2 x 3
  sex   data               quantiles
  <fct> <list>             <list>   
1 F     <tibble [491 × 1]> <dbl [5]>
2 M     <tibble [509 × 1]> <dbl [5]>
```

What is the elegant way of storing the five quantiles as five new columns of my data frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one option:

```
toydata %>%
  group_by(sex) %>%
  nest() %>%
  crossing(p) %>%
  mutate(
    quantiles = map2_dbl(data, p, ~quantile(.x$value, .y, na.rm=TRUE)),
    p = paste0('quantile_', p)
  ) %>%
  spread(p, quantiles)
```

Second option:

```
toydata %>%
  group_by(sex) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(
    quantiles = map_chr(data, ~quantile(.$value, p, na.rm=TRUE) %>% str_c(collapse = '_'))
  ) %>%
  separate(quantiles, paste0('quantile_', p), sep = '_') %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with('quantile')), as.numeric)
```

Output:

```
  sex   data               quantile_0.1 quantile_0.25 quantile_0.5 quantile_0.75 quantile_0.9
  <fct> <list>                    <dbl>         <dbl>        <dbl>         <dbl>        <dbl>
1 F     <tibble [512 x 1]>        -1.31        -0.758       0.0400         0.623         1.32
2 M     <tibble [488 x 1]>        -1.37        -0.795      -0.178          0.603         1.25
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, and beautiful at it. It looks like `purrr` always wants data in the longest format possible... Thanks!

Comment: Btw, the second options appears a bit more efficient when the dataset is large, as it does not require crossing.